# Adding new locale - hangs at Step 3 'ResaveAllElements'

Tags: localization, php, memory

I've looked at every option I can think of so hoping that someone can assist. We're on a dedicated server with full root access.

We've got a relatively small site that now needs a Spanish locale adding. When I go to add it, everything seems to be smooth running until 'ResaveAllElements - step 3' and 'ResaveElements - step 99 (sometimes around 94 ish too).

First thing I checked was the error log and found:

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes)
```

So, I then changed this to 1024M - no joy. Changed it to -1 and still get exactly the same issue. These settings are reflected in the phpinfo too so they seem to be in place.

I then phoned our server company and ran it by them who suggested placing .user.ini files in there to be sure and so we've done that and now we're at a loss.

I found another post on here with a similar issue where the suggestion was to examine the craft.log - did that and found:

```
WHERE (lft = 1) AND (status = :status). Bound with :status='running') 2016/08/12 09:36:53 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "components" application component in /*/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (593) in /*/craft/app/models/TaskModel.php (81) in /*/craft/app/models/TaskModel.php (39)
```

Is there anything else we can try to get the locale that we've missed?

Any help would much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you up [Craft's internal memory limit](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#phpMaxMemoryLimit), as well?

Comment: Perfect!! Completely missed that. Sorted, now just got a 'Resaving supertable blocks' failure when creating the locale. I'll create another post for that as it appears a separate issue.

Comment: That's great, @JonnyT – I'll add that as an answer, then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to up [Craft's internal memory limit](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#phpMaxMemoryLimit), as well – the following should go into the array in your `general.php` configuration file:

```
'phpMaxMemoryLimit' => '1024M',
```

Comment: Did everything in php.ini but that was the missing step!

Answer (score 1):

Just to record for others getting this error when adding Locales, I ran into this on Step 1 when ResaveElements for Assets. Seems that there were some entries in craft_assetfiles that no longer existed and caused the task to halt.

Managed to debug by checking the step number in craft_tasks, then looking for a row at that position in assetfiles that equated to a missing file. Removed a couple of these rows and the task completed fine.

I had Cleared Caches and Updated Indexes before starting, but seems there are still a few bad entries in the files table